# Batch - Quotes and parenthesis in variables which are used in IF statements

Tags: batch-file

I have been trying to convert my script to allow quotes and parenthesis to be used in arguments like

```
script.bat -filter "Example*"
script.bat -filter "example (3.8.1)"
```

Quotes and parenthesis can be removed from %1 but have to be preserved in ProgramName. Can the code below to be modified accepting quotes and parenthesis?

```
@echo off
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo.
set "programName="
set "filterOrName="
set "listSelected=false"

:parseLoop

echo arg1: %1

IF NOT "%1"=="" (

    IF "%1"=="-filter" (
        set filterOrName=%1
        IF NOT "%2"=="-filter" IF NOT "%2"=="-name" IF NOT "%2"=="-list" (
            set ProgramName=%2
        )
    )
    IF "%1"=="-name" (
        set filterOrName=%1
        IF NOT "%2"=="-filter" IF NOT "%2"=="-name" IF NOT "%2"=="-list" (
            set ProgramName=%2
        )
    )
    IF "%1"=="-list" (
        set "listSelected=true"
    )
    SHIFT
    GOTO :parseLoop
)

echo filterOrName: !filterOrName!
echo listSelected: !listSelected!
echo ProgramName: !ProgramName!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a common batch technic to always strip the outer quotes by using the `%~1` syntax.

And everywhere where the content is used, enclose it into quotes again.

```
...
IF "%~1"=="-filter"  ... 
set "programName=%~2"
...
echo start the program
"%programName%" argument1 argument2 ...
```

**Explanation of `set "programName=%~2"`:**
Here the quoted set syntax is used `set "varname=content"` (the first quote HAS to be in front of the varname).
This syntax stores the content into `<varname>` without quotes (only the ones if content has quotes itself).

This syntax avoids many problems, when the content contains special characters like `&<>|^`.
It also avoids accidential white spaces at the end of a `set var=content<space><space>`,  because any content after the last quote is dropped.

**Using delayed expansion**
Delayed expansion solves many problems when it comes to ouput arbitrary content.
And it avoids problems, when the content contains quotes or other special characters like `&|<>`
Delayed expansion has the advantage, that it can expand variables without interpreting the content later.

```
set "var=example (3.8.1)"
echo #1 %var% - works
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
  echo #2 !var! -- works
)
(
  echo #3 %var% -- fails because var contains a closing parentheses
)
```

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that the quoted `set "varname=content"` syntax requires the command extensions to be enabled (which is the default anyway)...

Comment: Thanks. What about parenthesis? Do I have to replace parenthesis with eg strings #parenthesisOpen# and #parenthesisClosed# and restore parenthesis after IF statements?

Comment: @JPX No, there aren't problems, as long as they are inside quotes. `IF "%str%" == "(abc)" ...`